# is Objective-c still under active support or died?

Tags: objective-c

I want to know if objective c is still under development or it will be

trashed and replaced forever with swift. I'm afraid that all my learning is

now worthless and useless, becouse many people is using swift more and

more. Is objective-c going keep get updated or did apple stop completely

updating it...

Comment: At this point in time, I don't think anyone knows what Apple's future plans are. I hope Obj-C sticks around, and it hasn't been deprecated or anything yet, but I guess we'll all see.

Comment: That would be very sad if they did... all my projects is written with Obj-C for mac and ios and i have great knowlage of it now.

Comment: Completely forget obj-c and work in Swift.

Comment: I know. I've go 5 apps on the store, and 4/5 are in Obj-C.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Is that supposed to be sarcastic?

Comment: Joe Blow that would be time and knowledge waste for me and many people. That would be not fair if Apple did. Swift as option would be better than replacing a whole lang... and Linuxios i feel you, i dont want to code for mac/ios if they did that.. i would go totally C/C++ with android.

Comment: Welcome to the world of software development. It's a continuous learning process. Just as you learned Objective-C, you will have to learn Swift. In about two years or so the majority of new code will be written in Swift; if you haven't learned it by that time you're out of business.

Comment: Of course it is not sarcastic. FORGET OBJECTIVE C, don't live in the past. You can pick up a new programming language or environment in 3 days.  (If you can't do that, you can't program.)

Comment: in answer to your literal question, apple are in the phase of paying lip service to "supporting" objectivec .. a couple more months and it will be dead and buried.  I mean swift arrived was A YEAR AND A HALF ago, it's computing for goodness sake.  3 months is a lifetime.  What's the big deal?  All programming languages are basically identical, what's the difference?  It's more about knowing all the Apple libraries. If you do, great.  Enjoy!

Comment: @JoeBlow Sorry but you are crazy. Objective-C is not going away in a few months. That's just silly talk. Too many people have too much investment in existing Objective-C code for Objective-C to simply go away. It will be many years, if ever, before Apple drops support for their APIs in Objective-C.

Comment: @JoeBlow: It's not about learning. I learned basic Swift quite quickly, but that doesn't mean I have the time to *port* my existing software to Swift (or, for that matter, that I like Swift. Personally, I don't, which makes it even less likely I'd make the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C is not going anywhere anytime soon.

It is very mature and been used for many years.

Most of the applications are written in objective-c.

Eventually objective-c programmer will be in high demand and probably better paid.

Don't get me wrong swift will take over but the industry don't move as fast as the technology as companies won't rewrite millions of line of code.

That being said apple encourage developer to use swift for new apps.

Comment: Thanks for the motivation... in this hard times we need it. :)

Comment: there are NO objectiveC jobs now.  it's all Swift.  why the heck would you start a new project in some dead system?  regarding "old" projects, they're only stupid apps, everything gets totally rewritten every couple yrs.

Comment: Exactly what my answer said swift recommended for new projects. Dont know where u live but in USA there tons of objc jobs

Comment: @JoeBlow: "Everything" does not get rewritten every few years. Contrary to popular belief, neither hot startup projects or individual indie developers always have the time or motivation to rewrite constantly.